# Jquery slide div changing css margin-left

Tags: jquery

I know, there are noumerous questions like this, but most of them too complicated and overloaded with code.

I want to slide between div's changing margin. It works fine with sliding right, but doen't work with sliding to left. I have absolutely equivalent code for both cases, but i'm missing something, can't figure out what.

```
$('#next').click(function(){
        var current = $('.selected');
        var next = current.next();
        if (next.length !=0) {

            width = current.width() + 'px';
            next.show().css({'margin-left': width});
            current.animate({'margin-left': -width}, 900, function(){
                current.hide().removeClass('selected');
            });
            next.animate({'margin-left': 0}, 900, function(){
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            });
        }
    })
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGLsG/149/)

You can see in the fiddle - when you click next, nex div slides in as it expected. But if you click prev - it doesn't slide. (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're switching which side is pushing/pulling when you're changing the margin side. You really just want to deal with the same side, but opposite values. So instead of switching to using `margin-right` in the css method and the animate method, have it use the same `margin-left`, but make the values opposite to other click method.

```
$('#prev').click(function(){
    var current = $('.selected');
    var next = current.prev();
    if (next.length !=0) {

        width = current.width() + 'px';
        next.show().css({'margin-left': -width});
        current.animate({'margin-left': width}, 900, function(){
            current.hide().removeClass('selected');
        });
        next.animate({'margin-left': 0}, 900, function(){
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
    }

})
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGLsG/150/)

Comment: No problem, sometimes it just takes some more pairs of eyes :)